# what does pomOnly() do in .sbt files?

Tags: scala, maven, sbt, pom.xml

what does pomOnly() do in .sbt files?

For example,

```
"com.github.fommil.netlib" % "all" % "1.0" pomOnly()
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Indeed, SBT reference guide does not seem to provide much info about `pomOnly()`.

As per [mvnrepository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.fommil.netlib/all/1.0), the dependency "com.github.fommil.netlib:all" corresponds to an aggregate pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.fommil.netlib</groupId>
  <artifactId>all</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

The call of `pomOnly()` in `build.sbt` indicates to the dependency management handlers that they should not look for jar libs/artifacts for this dependency, but only load the metadata from the aggregate pom.