# Spark org.apache.jena.shared.NoReaderForLangException: Reader not found: JSON-LD

Tags: apache-spark, sbt, jena, spark-structured-streaming, sbt-assembly

I am using Jena in Spark. I am facing a weird issue when I am deploying on the cluster (Does not happen on local Dev, for which i do not need to build an uber jar)

When I deploy on the cluster i get the following exceptions:

```
Caused by: org.apache.jena.shared.NoReaderForLangException: Reader not found: JSON-LD
 at org.apache.jena.rdf.model.impl.RDFReaderFImpl.getReader(RDFReaderFImpl.java:61)
at org.apache.jena.rdf.model.impl.ModelCom.read(ModelCom.java:305)
```

**1 -** I wonder, generally speaking where does an error like `org.apache.jena.shared.NoReaderForLangException: Reader not found: JSON-LD` may come/originate from ? Again this code works perfect in local mode.

**2 -** My Build.sbt Assembly strategy:

```scala
lazy val entellectextractorsmappers = project
  .settings(
      commonSettings,
      mainClass in assembly := Some("entellect.extractors.mappers.NormalizedDataMapper"),
      assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
        case "application.conf" => MergeStrategy.concat
        case "reference.conf"   => MergeStrategy.concat
        case PathList("META-INF", "services", "org.apache.jena.system.JenaSubsystemLifecycle") => MergeStrategy.concat
        case PathList("META-INF", "services", "org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister") => MergeStrategy.concat
        case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
        case x => MergeStrategy.first},
      dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % "2.9.5",
      dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.9.5",
      dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" % "jackson-module-scala_2.11" % "2.9.5",
      dependencyOverrides += "org.apache.jena" % "apache-jena" % "3.8.0",
      libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.apache.jena" % "apache-jena" % "3.8.0",
      "edu.isi" % "karma-offline" % "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT",
      "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.3.1" % "provided",
      "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.3.1" % "provided",
      "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql-kafka-0-10" % "2.3.1"
      //"com.datastax.cassandra" % "cassandra-driver-core" % "3.5.1"
    ))
  .dependsOn(entellectextractorscommon)
```

If anyone has a hint about using Jena and Spark, awesome, else any hints about what could cause the Reader not found: JSON-LD, as in when can that happens, or what does it means from the library standpoint. This way I can trace back, what in my packaging is causing it to happen.

Comment: Dependency "org.apache.jena" % "apache-jena" % "3.8.0" is strange - that is the binary downloads. "apache-jena-libs", which is <type>pom, is the correct dependency. http://jena.apache.org/download/maven.html

Comment: Yes I am, that is exactly what my SBT above does. It create one uber jar that contain my jena dependency. In the assembly strategy I have case PathList("META-INF", "services", "org.apache.jena.system.JenaSubsystemLifecycle") => MergeStrategy.concat

Comment: It needs to be <type>pom. "org.apache.jena" % "apache-jena" % "3.8.0" pomOnly() : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45608473/what-does-pomonly-do-in-sbt-files

Comment: Have you checked the service loader setup? Looking at the code, the MergeStrategy.concat looks to apply only to the specific list it operates on.

Comment: jena-core does not include the reader framework needed for JSON-LD nor does it have jsonld-java as a dependency.

Comment: @AndyS I have changed the pom type as you suggested. The problem is still there. I think I need some pointer as to where to look for the service loader setup. The only indication about how to combine the jars is here https://jena.apache.org/documentation/notes/jena-repack.html. I have followed basically what is done for fuseki jena-fuseki2/jena-fuseki-server/pom.xml

Comment: I have added the following to the merge strategy `case PathList("META-INF", "services",  xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.concat` based on the fact that the fuseki application of the service transformer, does not only focus on the resource org.apache.jena.system.JenaSubsystemLifecycle. So I guess it applies it to all the services resources. However i am not sure that things are merge per resource like the maven transformer does, or it is done across all the resources of all services across all the jar, that would be terrible. but so far it works for me. I need to understand better how assembly works.

Comment: Look in the merged jar and see if it is right.

Comment: Will edit my question to update add the response and add another question to understand what assembly does vs resource transformer.