# How are the different reader registered in Jena?

Tags: jena

Jena as of version 3.8.0 has several reader ? I wonder how those reader are register or made available to Jena API in general ? I'm having an exception of the type:

> ```
> > Caused by: org.apache.jena.shared.NoReaderForLangException: Reader not
> > found: JSON-LD  at
> > org.apache.jena.rdf.model.impl.RDFReaderFImpl.getReader(RDFReaderFImpl.java:61)
> >     at org.apache.jena.rdf.model.impl.ModelCom.read(ModelCom.java:305)
> ```

I am willing to track down, why this reader is not available in the context of my application, which is building a UBER Jar.

Any big jena internal Guru here that may help ?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52578547/spark-org-apache-jena-shared-noreaderforlangexception-reader-not-found-json-ld

Comment: http://jena.apache.org/download/maven.html and https://jena.apache.org/documentation/notes/jena-repack.html